# Export images embebbed in a Wordpress Database

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I have imported a Blogger account into a Wordpress installation. But suddenly I saw that the table `wp_posts` grow up to **128 MiB**, and I noticed that **inside** some posts there were embebbed images encoded in base64 like this

`<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...." />`

How can I export all these images outside the database, to the `wp-content` folder, and lighten the database?

Is there any kind of plugin doing that?

Some guidelines if not?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin named [Blogger Importer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogger-importer/). It should handle those images. If it doesn't, write your own importer. That's really simple. Then you have to `base64_decode()` the images and insert them into the upload directory with [`wp_insert_attachment()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment).

We have some questions about this topic on [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=blogger). Take a look at those and ask there for help if you get stuck.

Comment: The problem with Blogger Importer is that breaks all tags, and makes imported posts a bunch of nonsense. I will try that. Thank you.